# Создание массива циклом foreach

Tags: php, массивы, foreach

Пытаюсь создать массив такого вида:

```
Array
(
   [1565] => 5456
   [1564] => 23421
)
```

а получается почему такого:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [1565] => 5456
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [1564] => 23421
        )

)
```

Вот мой недокод:

```
$posts = get_posts(array(
    'posts_per_page'    => -1,
    'post_type'         => 'films'
));
if( $posts ):
    $arrId = [];
    foreach( $posts as $post ): 
        setup_postdata( $post );
        $arrFilmId[] = array($post->ID => get_field('film_id', $post->ID));
    endforeach;
endif;
```

что я не так делаю?

Answer (score 4):

Вместо

```
$arrFilmId[] = array($post->ID => get_field('film_id', $post->ID));
```

Используйте

```
$arrFilmId[$post->ID] = get_field('film_id', $post->ID);
```